# Duplicate identifier when trying to update objects in classes mapped using @DiscriminatorColumn / @DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have an application that uses spring and hibernate 5.2

We have a class MyAbstractClass :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class MyAbstractClass extends PersistentEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyClassPK myClassPK;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String        label;
}
```

a class myClassPK

```
@Embeddable MyClassPK :
public class MyClassPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "key1")
    @NotNull
    private String key1;

    @Column(name = "key2")
    @NotNull
    private String key2;
}
```

a class FirstChild

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DI1")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public class FirstChild extends MyAbstractClass {
}
```

and a class SecondChild :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DI2")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public class SecondChild extends MyAbstractClass {
}
```

We have a problem if we have two objects FirstChild a and SecondChild b having the same values for key1 and key2 :
we have a Duplicate identifier when we try to update one of them.

In database this would look like this :

```
key1|key2|discr |label     |
----+----+------+----------+
 A  | B  | DI1  |label 1   |
 A  | B  | DI2  |label 2   |
```

when we load an element, the generated query correctly refers the discriminator column but the discriminator column is missing in the update query :

```
update MYTABLE set LABEL=? where KEY1=? and KEY2=?
```

We beleive a correct query would be :

```
update MYTABLE set LABEL=? where KEY1=? and KEY2=? and DISCR='DI1'
```

We've read that hibernate only adds the modified columns to the update query but then how can we manage to update our objects without getting duplicate identifier exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that constellation then your discriminator (`discr`) **MUST** be part of the ID `MyClassPK`.